# How to mimic this doubly linked list animation using SplDoublyLinkedList?

Tags: php, data-structures, doubly-linked-list, spl

I was trying to reverse engineer this Doubly Linked List animation generated using this [tool](https://www.codelike.in/animation/doubly-linked-list):

[image]

So I've tried this:

```
<?php

$dll = new \SplDoublyLinkedList();

$dll->unshift(200);//inserir no início
$dll->unshift(100);//inserir no início
$dll->push(34);//inserir no final
$dll->push(35);//inserir no final
$dll->add(2, 3); //inserir em posicao específica
$dll->unshift(670);//inserir no início
$dll->add(($dll->count() / 2)-1, 450);//inserir no meio
$dll->pop(); //remover do final
$dll->shift(); //remover do início
$dll->offsetUnset(1);//remover de posicao específica

$prev = null;
$dll->rewind(); //rebobinando
while ($dll->valid()) {
    $current = $dll->current();
    echo 'Atual: '.$current, "\n";
    $dll->next();
}
```

But the result is different from the animation :(
How to mimic this doubly linked list animation and get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can mimic that animation using purely PHP, at least it won't be easy. You can somehow animate the output of the list content by printing it at each step, and using `sleep` to be able to observe the changes being outputed:

```
<?php

$dll = new \SplDoublyLinkedList();

// add 200 to the list using push. Unshift has the same effect because the list is empty
$dll->push(200);
output($dll);

// insert 100 at the beginning of the list
$dll->unshift(100); 
output($dll);

// add 34 the end of the list
$dll->push(34); 
output($dll);

// add 35 the end of the list
$dll->push(35);
output($dll);

// insert 3 on the second position (usually a loop to find the index would be necessary)
$dll->add(2, 3);
output($dll);

// insert 670 at the beginning of the list
$dll->unshift(670);
output($dll);

// add 450 on the third position 
$dll->add(3, 450);
output($dll);

// remove last element of the list
$dll->pop();
output($dll);

// remove first element of the list
$dll->shift();
output($dll);

// remove from position 1 (second linked list element)
$dll->offsetUnset(1); 
output($dll);

function output(&$dll) {
    ob_start();

    $dll->rewind();

    $values = [];
    while ($dll->valid()) {
        $values[] = $dll->current();
        $dll->next();
    }

    echo "[ " . implode(' , ', $values) . " ] \n"; //on the browser change \n to <br>

    ob_end_flush();
    //ob_flush(); // enable on the browser
    flush();

    sleep(1); // wait one second
}
```